# Can't set element ID in JavaScript, it's always undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a function that generates ID's on the fly for a given jquery object, if it doesn't have one already. These ID's should then be used in future requests.

I came up with the code below, but it doesn't work. The ID's are never set. The commented out alert statement below always return undefined.

I always pass code like $(this) or $(options.el) as a parameter to substitute 'el'. Initially, the elements do not have explicitly ID set in HTML.

Any help would be appreciated, here's the code:

```
getElementId: function(el) 
{
   if(undefined == el.attr('id'))
   {
      el.attr('id',"anim-"+Math.random().toString().substr(2));
   }
   // alert(el.attr('id'));
   return el.attr('id');
},
```

Comment: What browser have you tried this in? Is your if statement evaluating to true? i.e., if you add an alert before your `el.attr('id', 'anim...` does it execute? you can try stepping through your code in firebug and see if it breaks on that statement

Comment: are you getting any errors? Is `el` a jQuery object? If it is not then `.attr` wont work for you.

Comment: you can also try `if((typeof(el.attr('id'))).toString() == 'undefined') { `

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with the code. Could you post a more-complete example? http://jsfiddle.net is a useful tool for this.

Comment: Check against `""` instead of undefined? An element without an `attr` returns `""`, not undefined, and `undefined != ""`.

Comment: @Jaitsu: `typeof` is an operator, not a function, so the parentheses are unnecessary in this case. `typeof` always returns a string, to the `toString()` call is completely unnecessary. And, since you know you're always comparing strings to strings, you should be using `===` (the strict equality operator), **not** `==` (the type-coercing equality operator).

Comment: If `el` is not a jquery object, you can always just use `el.id`.  Sometimes jQuery's functionality isn't necessary.

Comment: @Matt Ball, the parentheses make it easier to read sometimes so that's just false habit... also in some older browsers I've seen that check fail without the toString() call,

Comment: @Jaitsu I've tried it in latest FF and Chrome. Yes, the IF evaluates to true EVERY time, as if the id was never set. I've checked it with FireBug.

Comment: @Matt Ball:  *"...since you know you're always comparing strings to strings, you should be using `===`"* When you know you're always comparing the same type (strings to strings in this case), it doesn't matter if you use `==` or `===` since the algorithm will be identical. :o)

Comment: @patrick: I see almost no reason to use `==` instead of `===`, ever.

Comment: @Matt Ball: I personally only use `==` when I have a specific purpose for type coercion (usually when I'm doing `x == null`). My point is that it doesn't make sense to say you shouldn't use the type-coercing operator when there will be no type-coercion. In such a case, it makes no difference which you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

`if(undefined == el.attr('id'))`

to:

`if("" == el.attr('id'))`

Comment: jQuery returns en empty string on unset attributes... Don't ask me why, even the doc says it should return undefined but a real life test shows it returns an empty string, see http://jsfiddle.net/d8Nmc/

Comment: Thx for the investigation @Matt Ball!

Answer (score 4):

Test the truthiness of the valued returned by `.attr()`, and make sure that `el` is actually a jQuery object.

```
getElementId: function(el) 
{
   if (!el.jquery)
   {
       el = $(el);
   }
   
   if(!el.attr('id'))
   {
      el.attr('id',"anim-"+Math.random().toString().substr(2));
   }
   // alert(el.attr('id'));
   return el.attr('id');
},
```

**Depending on the attribute you're trying to retrieve,** [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) may return `undefined` or `""`.

---

Other recommended cleanup:

```
getElementId: function(el) 
{
   if (!el.jquery)
   {
       el = $(el);
   }
   
   var id = el.attr('id');
   
   if(!id)
   {
      // make sure this ID hasn't actually been used before!
      do
      {
          id = "anim-"+Math.random().toString().substr(2);
      } while (!$('#' + id).length);
      el.attr('id', id);
   }
   
   return id;
},
```

You **really** need to make sure that you're not assigning an ID to that element which has already been used before. The above function does this. A simpler way to accomplish the same thing is to use an incrementing counter stored somewhere outside of the scope of the function:

```
__idCounter__: 1,
getElementId: function(el) 
{
   if (!el.jquery)
   {
       el = $(el);
   }
   
   var id = el.attr('id');
   
   if(!id)
   {
      id = "anim-" + (this.__idCounter__++);
      el.attr('id', id);
   }
   
   return id;
},
```

---

#### Last edit (I promise)

There seems to be confusion about what `.attr()` returns when an element does not have the attribute requested. After running [some tests](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/TZmW4/), it looks like `.attr()` returns:

- the empty string for *at least* `id` and `class` (perhaps other HTML4-spec attributes as well; didn't test)
- `undefined` for other attributes not defined by the spec

Output from [my tests](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/TZmW4/):

```
<div id="myID"/> id: myID
<div id="myID"/> class: 
<div id="myID"/> data-attr: undefined
<div id="myID"/> asdf: undefined

<div class="myClass"/> id: 
<div class="myClass"/> class: myClass
<div class="myClass"/> data-attr: undefined
<div class="myClass"/> asdf: undefined

<div data-attr="myAttr"/> id: 
<div data-attr="myAttr"/> class: 
<div data-attr="myAttr"/> data-attr: myAttr
<div data-attr="myAttr"/> asdf: undefined

<div asdf="myNonSpecAttr"/> id: 
<div asdf="myNonSpecAttr"/> class: 
<div asdf="myNonSpecAttr"/> data-attr: undefined
<div asdf="myNonSpecAttr"/> asdf: myNonSpecAttr
```

---

#### tl;dr

Just test the truthiness of the value returned by `.attr()`, since that treats `undefined` and `""` (the empty string) the same:

```
if (somejQueryElt.attr('someAttr'))
{
    // it definitely has the attribute
}
else
{
    // it definitely does not have the attribute
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find any element/attribute exists in DOM you need to use `length` property :
Proper condition is :

```
if (el.attr('id').length > 0 )
```

Full function:

```
getElementId: function (el) {
    return el.attr('id').length > 0 ? el.attr('id') : el.attr('id', "anim-" + Math.random().toString().substr(2));
}
```

Comment: This is misguided advice. Yes, you use `length` to determine if a jQuery object is empty, but the same does not hold for attributes, which are just strings. If `.attr()` returns `undefined` (which it does in jQuery 1.5 for nonexistent attributes), then checking the `length` property will throw an exception.

Comment: @ Matt Ball : i assumed that he is using jquery 1.5 prior. unless only checking if(!el.attr('id')) would work.

Comment: I did a little investigating and it looks like I was wrong about when `.attr()` returns `""` vs `undefined` (see my edit). You nailed it, however: just check `if(!el.attr('id'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a simple debugging statement in your code would show you why no id is being set.

```
getElementId: function(el) 
{
   alert(el.attr('id'));
   if(console)console.log(el.attr('id'));
   if(undefined == el.attr('id'))
   {
      el.attr('id',"anim-"+Math.random().toString().substr(2));
   }
   // alert(el.attr('id'));
   return el.attr('id');
},
```

You will see the alert does not return undefined. It returns an empty string

```
getElementId: function(el) 
{
   var id = el.attr('id');
   if(id.length===0)
   {
      id="anim-"+Math.random().toString().substr(2);               
      el.attr('id',id);
   }
   return id;
},
```

I also hope you know that math.random is really not random. You should have some sort of counter.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your condition should be like this:

`if (typeof el.attr('id') === 'undefined')`

Comment: Using jQuery, attr() on a non existent attribute will never be undefined, it will be an empty string, see @pimvdb correct answer

Comment: Aaaah, it returns an empty string in jQuery 1.4, how vicious is that?

Comment: And jQuery 1.5 returns en empty string on Fiddle. The doc is wrong or this is a bug... See http://jsfiddle.net/d8Nmc/